# In playwright asserting a locator for visibility vs asserting for a text in that locator for visibility

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Consider below div -

```
<div data-testid="textid">some text</div>
```

**What I want to do** : I want to assert if the text `some text` is visible on the screen.

Which one is correct way to assert and why, because both seems to work for me.

`await expect(page.getByText("some text")).toBeVisible();` OR
`await expect(page.getByTestId("textid")).toBeVisible();`

Thanks!

Comment: The first one should work

Comment: Pretty clearly, the second one doesn't test the text at all since the string ``"some text"` is nowhere in the code. You'd need to change it to `await expect(page.getByTestId("textid")).toHaveText("some text");` for it to take `"some text"` into consideration in any way. If you use the first one, keep it mind it may choose a different element than you think if the text is common enough, so it's use-case specific as far as which is "better", after the fix to #2. Without context, its hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following for exact text:

```
await expect(page.getByTestId("textid")).toHaveText("some text")
```

Link: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text

Comment: Interesting, I like this solution better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should combine both of them together using locator [and](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-and) condition to verify the correct text at the right location.

```
await expect(page.getByTestId("testid").and(page.getByText("someText"))).toBeVisible()
```

Alternate solution using XPath with locator:

```
const locator= '//*[@data-testid="testid" and text()="someText"]

await expect(locator).toBeVisible()
```